# How did Jimmy end up with Freddy the magic flute?

Tags: magical-creatures, hrpufnstuf

As any Saturday Morning Cartoons fan from the late 60's and early 70's can tell you, *[H.R. Pufnstuf](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063907/?ref_=ttep_ep_tt)* was quite an [adventure](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=hr%20pufnstuf%20theme%20song&FORM=VIRE1#view=detail&mid=F59C3D4AADFE86472DFAF59C3D4AADFE86472DFA). Live action, puppets, dancing trees, good vs. evil. The story goes something like this: Jimmy has a magic flute named Freddy. The witch from Living Island (where everything is alive) wants the flute and tricks Jimmy into bringing his flute with him on her charmed boat. H.R. Pufnstuf gets in the way and thwarts her attempts to lay her hands on Freddy every episode.

After some fruitless interweb research, my question is: Did Sid and Marty Krofft, the producers of H.R. Pufnstuf, ever reveal the Jimmy/Freddy backstory prior to Jimmy's boat ride, or did they leave the tale open ended? If they did provide an answer, what was it?? [image: flute]

Comment: This show had more drug references than a Snoop Dogg/Amy Winehouse collaborative album.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the start of the [1970 Pufnstuf movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pufnstuf_%28film%29), we get a bit more back-story on Jimmy and Freddy the Flute. Jimmy arrives late for band practice and is "expelled from the band" for causing a disruption and inadvertently breaking a drum kit. Fearing his parent's wrath, Jimmy runs into the woods where he throws his, at that time perfectly normal flute onto the ground. We hear a magical sound, then the flute turns into Freddy.

**Where did he get the flute from in the first place?**
It seem likely that his parents bought it for him from a shop.

**Why is the flute magical?**
It's not explained.

**Is this whole thing playing out in Jimmy's head after eating psychoactive mushrooms in the forest?**
Yes, that seems very likely.

**No, but seriously, is this whole film a massive drugs reference?**
Yes. Yes it is.

[image]

Comment: lol. Thanks for the justification. Now I can use the wayback machine guilt free to gather mushrooms.